# Can't launch mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I don't know where I went wrong, 
but there is an error after error going on here, first it was

```
STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongodb, terminating
```

I fixed with addition of permissions with this command:

```
sudo chmod -R go+w /var/lib/mongodb
```

, then

```
couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/local.0 Operation not permitted
```

fixed it with another sort of permissions(

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/lib/mongodb
```

)

now its complaining about:

```
F JOURNAL  [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13544 recover error couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
2017-11-20T13:19:16.443+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13544 recover error couldn't open /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0, terminating
```

Update: 
Fixed that as well with

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

now its

```
exception in initAndListen: 13440 bad offset:0 accessing file: /var/lib/mongodb/local.0. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/data-recovery, terminating
```

what is happening? I mean my Ubuntu is not some super secured version,
I wish there was some

```
mongod --repair
```

command for me to use, but there isn't, whenever I try to do it it complains about

```
exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

although in the etc/mongod.config the specified path is /var/lib/mongodb (that's where I was giving all this permissions at)
Edit:
fixed that with the CMD "do sudo mkdir /data", the repair run its course successfully, but it didn't help me.

so what do I do? how to fix it?
 how to run the Mongodb?

additional info: I ran it using

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: I can give you hint this issue was also with me. Mongodb have data directory , it is set automatically . But in your case it is not set . Two work around you can try . Run command with sudo , may be not able to create folder . Second create a folder /data/db . And also check how to set data directory of MongoDB . I am not confirm what i have done on that day . Hope this help you

Comment: where to create the /data/db directory?

Comment: /data/db means `/` means in root `do sudo mkdir /data` and inside it crate db .  It just the hint . I am not sure what i have done that day.

Comment: Thank you, I went one step further in my quest.

Comment: If you able solve the issue in somepoint . Add the answer , so that other can get help from that.