# how to return MongoDB to its initial state(delete all the database('s))

Tags: mongodb

I tried to run a mongoDB with corrupted files, now it won't load, won't start. how do I get rid of this corrupted files now? can I just delete the contents of 'var/lib/mongodb'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you don't need any of your data, just delete the files there. It will remove all the data, indexes and metadata.

If you are running in a replica set, you can do this too and it will automatically download all the data from one of the other healthy nodes which is really cool!

Answer (score 0):

```
var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in dbs){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( dbs[i] );
    print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );
    db.dropDatabase();
}
```

save it to dropall.js and then execute:

```
mongo dropall.js
```

Comment: My mongo is not running due to the corrupted files.
" Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017" 
whenever I try to do something 'mongo' related in the command line

Comment: Delete the lock file `\data\db\mongod.lock`, and run `mongod --repair`.

Comment: Yeah, I had quite a fight trying to recover the database, I documented it over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390986/cant-launch-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment81739682_47390986

mongod --repair was one of the things I tried.